# Find all combinations of just some elements of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional numpy array and a list of objects, some of the values of the numpy array are None

what would be the best way to find all possible combinations to fill the None values with the objects from the list?

for example if my array is

```
arr = [
    [1, None, 3],
    [9, 4, None],
]
```

and the list is

```
ls = [9, 8]
```

I want to find these

```
arr = [
    [1, 9, 3],
    [9, 4, 8],
]  
arr = [
    [1, 8, 3],
    [9, 4, 9],
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use a mask to fill the array's non-valid entries with the values in `ls`, as many times as **permutations** there are of `ls`.

However, this can be made more robust by setting the length of these permutations to the amount of non-valid entries in `arr`. That way we also account for the case `len(ls) > (x == None).sum()`.

The permutations can be obtained using [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
def fill_combs(x, fill, replace=None):
    from itertools import permutations
    m = x == replace
    for i in permutations(fill, int(m.sum())):
        x_ = x.copy()
        x_[m] = np.array(i)
        yield x_.astype(int)
```

Sample run:

```
arr = np.array([
    [1, None, 3],
    [9, 4, None],
])
ls = [9, 8]

list(fill_with_permut(arr, ls))
```

Output:

```
[array([[1, 9, 3],
        [9, 4, 8]]), 
 array([[1, 8, 3],
        [9, 4, 9]])]
```

Or for a larger `ls`:

```
ls = [3,5,2]
list(fill_with_permut(arr, ls))

[array([[1, 3, 3],
        [9, 4, 5]]), 
 array([[1, 3, 3],
        [9, 4, 2]]), 
 array([[1, 5, 3],
        [9, 4, 3]]), 
 array([[1, 5, 3],
        [9, 4, 2]]), 
 array([[1, 2, 3],
        [9, 4, 3]]),
 array([[1, 2, 3],
        [9, 4, 5]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def update(arr, items):
    count = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        if None in x:
            arr[i][x.index(None)] = items[count]
            count += 1
    return arr

import itertools
ls = [9, 8]
ls_ = list(itertools.permutations(ls))

for items in ls_:
    arr = [[1, None, 3],
           [9, 4, None]]
    print (update(arr,items))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 9, 3], [9, 4, 8]]
[[1, 8, 3], [9, 4, 9]]
```

example:  `ls = [9, 8, 15]`

output:

```
[[1, 9, 3], [9, 4, 8]]
[[1, 9, 3], [9, 4, 15]]
[[1, 8, 3], [9, 4, 9]]
[[1, 8, 3], [9, 4, 15]]
[[1, 15, 3], [9, 4, 9]]
[[1, 15, 3], [9, 4, 8]]
```